# proper modeling of cyclic relationships

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design, relational-database, relationship

I am having trouble in modeling this database. Basically, I have three entities, namely A, B and C, such that:

1. A has the primary key A_id.
2. A and B has a zero-to-many relationship, so B may have as primary key the pair (A_id, B_id).
3. A and C has a zero-to-many relationship, so C may have as primary key the pair (A_id, C_id).
4. B and C have a many-to-many relationship. Therefore, I may create an auxiliary table called BC having as primary key the 4-tuple (A_id1, B_id, A_id2, C_id), where (A_id1, B_id) is the foreign key to table B and (A_id2, C_id) is the foreign key to table C.

Everything is fine. However, a 5th requirement makes this design pretty useless: the related B and C tuples must be related to the same tuple of A, that is, A_id1 = A_id2, always.

My question is: how can I modify my design to guarantee all the requirements?

Comment: Can't you just make table BC as (A_id, B_id, C_id)?

Comment: how do I implement that?

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. If I understand your requirements, that should do it. Let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should meet all the requirements.

```
create table a(a_id number);
alter table a add constraint pk_a primary key(a_id);

create table b(a_id number, b_id number);
alter table b add constraint pk_b primary key(a_id, b_id);
alter table b add constraint fk_b_a foreign key(a_id) references a(a_id);

create table c(a_id number, c_id number);
alter table c add constraint pk_c primary key(a_id, c_id);
alter table c add constraint fk_c_a foreign key(a_id) references a(a_id);

create table bc(a_id number, b_id number, c_id number);
alter table bc add constraint pk_bc primary key(a_id, b_id, c_id);
alter table bc add constraint fk_bc_ab foreign key(a_id, b_id) references b(a_id, b_id);
alter table bc add constraint fk_bc_ac foreign key(a_id, c_id) references c(a_id, c_id);
```